# Web Services android app

Tags: php, android, web-services

i have developed a web services for a messaging API in php for android app, what response I need to send for the app? POST data is not working on the UI. I am a new developer, Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best you use a json object for the reply.
If you have your data in an array you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
Just echo the json on the php, that's what the android app will see.

*Edit

To parse the json on tha android side see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

and for validating the Json check http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

[image]